# How to translate Vuetify's material design color names into hexadecimal values in a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, vue-component, vuetify.js

I would like to get a [Vuetify material design color](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/) as a hexadecimal value in my Vue component's template so I can do something like this below to get, say, the string `#FFD54F`:

```html
<div :style="`border: 5px solid ${ myHexadecimalColor('amber lighten-2') }`">
</div>
```

I read the Vuetify docs' [SASS Variables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/) and [Colors](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors) sections, but I could not determine a solution from this.

I can see [the colors defined in Vuetify's github repo](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/53dae46faf4949053c7abcadc6b55897b767c8f0/packages/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_colors.scss) @ `vuetify/packages/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_colors.scss`, but I can't figure out how to get access to these Sass variables in my Vue single file component.

Does anyone know the best way to translate a Vuetify material design color name into its hexadecimal values?

---

**Bonus - Vuetify 2 name-to-hexidecimal function**

Based on Boussadjra Brahim's answer, I wrote a quick color-name-to-hexadecimal method to put in a Vue mixin, and included it below in case it is helpful to anyone.

Example: `hexColor('amber lighten-2')` returns `#FFD54F`

```js
import colors from 'vuetify/lib/util/colors'

methods: {
  hexColor: (name) => {
    const [nameFamily, nameModifier] = name.split(' ')
    const shades = ['black', 'white', 'transparent']
    const util = {family: null, modifier: null}
    if (shades.find(shade => shade === nameFamily)){
      util.family = 'shades'
      util.modifier = nameFamily
    } else {
      const [firstWord, secondWord] = nameFamily.split('-')
      util.family = `${ firstWord }${ secondWord
        ? secondWord.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + secondWord.slice(1)
        : '' }`
      util.modifier = nameModifier 
        ? nameModifier.replace('-', '') 
        : 'base'
    }
    return colors[util.family][util.modifier]
  }
}
```

---

**Update - Vuetify 3 name-to-hexidecimal function**

Here's a version of `hexColor()` for Vuetify 3. This is necessary because color names have changed from e.g. `blue lighten-2` to `blue-lighten-2`

```js
import colors from 'vuetify/lib/util/colors'

hexColor: (name) => {
  const baseColors = ['red','pink','purple','deep-purple','indigo','blue','light-blue','cyan','teal','green','light-green','lime','yellow','amber','orange','deep-orange','brown','blue-grey','grey']
  const shades = ['black', 'white', 'transparent']
  const match = [...baseColors,...shades].find(c => name.startsWith(c)) || null
  const remainder = match 
    ? name.slice(match.length) 
    : null
  const base = match.replace(/[-_](.)/g, (_, char) => char.toUpperCase());
  const variety = remainder 
    ? remainder.replaceAll('-','')
    : 'base'
  const nameStructured = shades.find(shade => match === shade) 
    ? { base:'shades', variety:base}
    : { base:base, variety:variety}
  return colors[nameStructured.base][nameStructured.variety]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the colors into your component then access the color with it modifier like :

```
import colors from 'vuetify/lib/util/colors'

....

<div :style="`border: 5px solid ${ colors['amber']['lighten2'] }`"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, while the accepted answer is correct, I think a more complete function would also include the ability to translate theme-color (such as `success`, `error`) and their shades (such as `success darken-2`), as well as handle inputs when the colors are already passed as hex, rgb or rgba.

Here's a function which I implemented into a mixin which does this:

```js
import colors from 'vuetify/lib/util/colors';
...
methods: {
    translateColor(color) {
        if ('string' !== typeof color || color.trim().length == 0) {
            return color;
        }
        if (color.startsWith('#') || color.startsWith('rgb')) {
            return color;
        }
        const themeColors = Object.keys(this.$vuetify.theme.currentTheme);
        const themeColorIndex = themeColors.indexOf(color);
        if (themeColorIndex > -1) {
            return this.$vuetify.theme.currentTheme[color];
        }
        let baseColor;
        let shade;
        if (color.includes(' ')) {
            const [bc, s] = color.split(' ');
            baseColor = bc;
            shade = s;
        }
        else {
            baseColor = color;
            shade = 'base';
        }
        const generalColors = Object.keys(colors);
        const generalColorsIndex = generalColors.indexOf(baseColor);
        const themeColorsShadeIndex = themeColors.indexOf(baseColor);
        if (generalColorsIndex > -1) {
            const fixedShade = shade.toLowerCase().replace('-', '');
            const co = colors[generalColors[generalColorsIndex]];
            return co[fixedShade];
        }
        else if (themeColorsShadeIndex > -1) {
            const fixedShade = shade.toLowerCase().replace('-', '');
            const co = this.$vuetify.theme.parsedTheme[themeColors[themeColorsShadeIndex]]
            return co[fixedShade];
        }
        return color;
    }
}
```

Now I'm sure my approach can be optimized, but the general idea is that it's able to read from both the included Material Design colors and the theme's colors.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer for Vue3 / Vuetify 3**

Here's the approach that I took with my recent Nuxt 3 project:

```js
import colors from "vuetify/lib/util/colors";
import { vuetify } from "~/plugins/vuetify";

export default function colorToCssColor(color?: string): string {
  if (typeof color !== "string" || color.trim().length === 0) {
    return color as string;
  }
  if (color.startsWith("#") || color.startsWith("rgb")) {
    return color;
  }
  const themeColors = vuetify.theme.current.value.colors;
  const stringToColor = new Map<string, string>([
    ["black", colors.shades.black],
    ["white", colors.shades.white],
    ["transparent", colors.shades.transparent],
  ]);
  const regularColors = [
    "red",
    "pink",
    "purple",
    "deepPurple",
    "indigo",
    "blue",
    "lightBlue",
    "cyan",
    "teal",
    "green",
    "lightGreen",
    "lime",
    "yellow",
    "amber",
    "orange",
    "deepOrange",
    "brown",
    "blueGrey",
    "grey",
  ] as const;
  regularColors.forEach((regularColor) => {
    stringToColor.set(regularColor, colors[regularColor].base);
    stringToColor.set(
      `${regularColor}-lighten-1`,
      colors[regularColor].lighten5
    );
    stringToColor.set(
      `${regularColor}-lighten-2`,
      colors[regularColor].lighten4
    );
    stringToColor.set(
      `${regularColor}-lighten-3`,
      colors[regularColor].lighten3
    );
    stringToColor.set(
      `${regularColor}-lighten-4`,
      colors[regularColor].lighten2
    );
    stringToColor.set(
      `${regularColor}-lighten-5`,
      colors[regularColor].lighten1
    );
    stringToColor.set(`${regularColor}-darken-6`, colors[regularColor].darken1);
    stringToColor.set(`${regularColor}-darken-7`, colors[regularColor].darken2);
    stringToColor.set(`${regularColor}-darken-8`, colors[regularColor].darken3);
    stringToColor.set(`${regularColor}-darken-9`, colors[regularColor].darken4);
  });
  for (const key in themeColors) {
    if (!key.startsWith("on-")) {
      stringToColor.set(key, themeColors[key as keyof typeof themeColors]);
    }
  }
  const val = stringToColor.get(color);
  if (val) {
    return val;
  }
  return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the helpers already present in Vuetify:

For Vuetify 2:

```js
import { classToHex, isCssColor } from "vuetify/lib/util/colorUtils";
import colors from "vuetify/lib/util/colors";

const color = "primary";
const currentTheme = this.$vuetify.theme.currentTheme;
const cssColor = !isCssColor(color)
  ? classToHex(color, colors, currentTheme)
  : color;
console.log(cssColor);
```